# How to use easytimer.js in my React app?

Tags: reactjs, timer

I'm trying to use [easytimer.js](http://albert-gonzalez.github.io/easytimer.js/) in my React app (used create-react-app). But I got the following error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/easytimer.js
  Line 10:  'define' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 11:  'define' is not defined  no-undef
```

Here's [my code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yglbqufodiqp6gv/easytimer-test-react.zip?dl=0).

I tested on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kmrzky8wj3) and it runs without any errors.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: someone already but it into an npm package, which maby is easier to use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/easytimer

Comment: @MaddEye Yes your solution works, thank you. Now I have a different error (TypeError: Cannot read property 'timer' of undefined at line 19). Not sure how to keep the reference to timer...can someone help?
https://gist.github.com/noblesilence/f27baef6beda6edf8a6569cbb925b8fd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your Solution

[image: Edit z34pwmy1mm]

Timer.js Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import EasyTimer from "easytimer";

class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            timer: new EasyTimer(),
            timeValues: ""
        };

        this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let { timer } = this.state;
        timer.start();
        timer.addEventListener("secondsUpdated", this.tick);
    }

    tick(e) {
        let { timer } = this.state;
        const timeValues = timer.getTimeValues().toString();
        this.setState({ timeValues: timeValues });
    }

    render() {
        return <div className="App">{this.state.timeValues}</div>;
    }
}

export default App;
```